# Simple bookkeeping software

Tags: software-recommendation

Looking for recommendations for simple bookkeeping software for Linux. Basic check register. Prefer to be able to transfer existing basic data from Quicken if possible.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like [GnuCash](http://www.gnucash.org/) is a good program for accounting. It can import QFX files (one for each account) from Quicken, and it will try to not keep duplicate entries. It also has a checkbook-style register, as you mentioned.

From their website:

Designed to be easy to use, yet powerful and flexible, GnuCash allows you to track bank accounts, stocks, income and expenses. As quick and intuitive to use as a checkbook register, it is based on professional accounting principles to ensure balanced books and accurate reports.

[image]